# Error when importing mysql.connector: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, backend, mysql-connector

Currently I am trying to link a server I have created with the InfinityFree hosting service (I am using it to host a website) to python backend scripts. I tried to establish a connection via this code:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="sql308.epizy.com",
  user="epiz_32101998",
  password="NRPbGbvzw7bLYK6",
  database="epiz_32101998_evogenesisTest"
)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'mysql'
  File "C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Desktop\EvoGenesis Website\database.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have installed python, mysql and mysql.connector and they are all updated. I am using vscode on a Windows 11 system. Other fixes that I have encountered for this probelem have involved making sure I am using the right python environment? I'm not sure what that means, but when I try to run other python code in that file or import packages lke pygame or random it works fine.

(Also mysql and mysql.connector do appear when i do pip list, so they are definitely installed)

Comment: You need to provide more information about the environment. Is this code running locally? How are you executing the code? What is the filename for the first snippet? Show more context around the error (i.e. prompts, previous cli etc.). "Using the right python environment" is probably related to pyenv or virtualenv vs. globally installed version – that sort of thing. Also did you install `mysql-connector-python`?

Comment: @geoidesic,  I am running  the code locally on my computer. I am excecuting it via vscode's default debug run command (f5).  I have installed the mysql-connector-python module. In terms of environment, I'm still not really sure what that it. I suppose it would the the system default - is that the 'globally installed version'? In reference to Noel George's answer, whilst I don't know if i'm using pyenv or not, I have not set up a virtual enviornment however vscode does allow us to choose a python interpreter when ctl + shift + p is pressed.

Comment: ^^ so then I could choose a particular option if you could specify the path I should use.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:
After having a look at where it was installed and running the python .exe file from earlier in that branch as my interpreter (as I've said, I can select this on VSCode via ctrl + shift + p) it worked. Turns out the issue was that I had both python 3.10 and 3.11 on my device. Still wondering how I'd install the mysql module on 3.11 if anyone knows?

Comment: You should ask a different question on Stackoverflow and reference this one, if you want to get that answered.

Comment: Ah thanks. I might do that if this becomes an issue but for the moment it's not really affecting my development so I'll hold off on that for now